# Is there a way to use mybatis compatible with jakarta?

Tags: mybatis

I currently have a project that depends on Google Guice (5.1.0) and org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.13
Now I have to update Google Guice to 7.0.0 which uses jakarta instead of javax.
That, though, makes it incompatible with MyBatis. For instance, MyBatisModule uses javax.inject.Provider not com.google.inject.Provider.
see: https://github.com/mybatis/guice/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mybatis/guice/MyBatisModule.java

Is there a way to use mybatis with jakarta?

Comment: There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/mybatis/guice/pull/576) for that. I am not a user, but if you could 1) build a local snapshot with the change, 2) test it with your app and 3) add a feedback comment to the PR, it might help the review process.

Comment: @ave Thanks a lot. I have check it and made the comment on the PR (https://github.com/mybatis/guice/pull/576#issuecomment-1729048591)
I was not able to test the entire application as I have some other incompatibilities to take care of. But at least the application has compiled with this shapshort.